# Using an if statment within awk to check if one variable meets a format if so follow this path

Tags: awk

I want to be able to check the data held in one variable if the data inside is "B" then use this regex if it contains something else use a different regex

```
awk '{if ($1 == "B")
($2 ~ /^".+"$/) && (length($2) <= 10)     {print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";}
else
($2 ~ /^".+"|""$/) && (length($2) <= 10)   {print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";}
'
```

Sample input

```
$1 == "B"
$2 == "random string"
```

Expected output

there should be no output as the regex passed

alt sample input

```
$1 == "B"
$2 == "null/empty
```

Expected output

there should be `45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE` displayed on screen

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: sample input would be $44 == B and then expected output would be the if statement following `($45 ~ /^".+"$/) && (length($45) <= 2502)     {print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";}` however if $44 has no B inside it would follow `($45 ~ /^".+"|""$/) && (length($45) <= 2502)   {print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";}`

Comment: Still not clear, why you are taking or considering a condition as an Input? Kindly put more light on same.

Comment: so variable $44 is a field in a csv file and can be either a B or a number of other things and if its a B I need it to make $45 mandatory hence the lack of a |"" in the else path. hope this clears it up for you

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I would like to request you again to please post samples of input and expected output(only samples) in your POST and let us know then.

Comment: look at op @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:
The conditions can combine:
`($45 ~ /^".+"$/) && (length($45) <= 2502)`  to `($45~/^".{1,2500}"$/)`.
`($45 ~ /^".+"|""$/) && (length($45) <= 2502)` to `($45~/^".{0,2500}"$/)`.

Also, if there's no quote inside the quotes (and should be like that), more exactly:
`($45~/^"[^"]{1,2500}"$/)` and `($45~/^"[^"]{0,2500}"$/)`.
So you can do the checking like this:

```
awk '
    $44 == "B" && ($45~/^"[^"]{1,2500}"$/) {print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";}  # <-- You can add next inside, after the semicolon, if there are no other codes need to execute.
    $44 != "B" && ($45~/^"[^"]{0,2500}"$/) {print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";}
'
```

Since it's simply equal or not, so just `AND` the different conditions of `$44 == "B"` and `$44 != "B"` to other conditions will serve your need.

Or, put them all inside the main block, and quote them correctly, like this:

```
awk '
{
    if ($44 == "B") {
        if ($45~/^"[^"]{1,2500}"$/) {
            print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";
        } 
    } else {
        if ($45~/^"[^"]{0,2500}"$/) {
            print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE";
        }
    }
}'
```

When properly quoted and indented, you can see the structure clearly.

BTW, you can change `length($45) <= 2502` to `length($45) < 2503` for conciseness, since `length` returns an integer.

Comment: sorry @tiw I refreshed and yours and james answer swapped place :) sorry about that and yes your work but for reason they take an awfully long time to run :) so just for clarification without your code about 1.5-2.5 seconds with your code about 8 mins im trying to work out why now

Comment: @jordanb111 I'm guessing it's the regex taking the time, and your true data has a big quantity of lines, is it right? Also I'm guessing inside the quotes `""` there's no quote inside, so I changed the regex to `[^"]`, that will speed up a little bit.

Comment: so at the moment my test file is just 4 lines of data so not too big but yes it was the regex last time hence why I changed from using the regex character limit to a separate length method

Comment: @jordanb111  I see. Then you can further testing it using other ways. One way is to use `substr` to test the qutoes. Although it will be more complex, but maybe will speed it up.  Also if one branch's execution possibility is way bigger than another, you can move that branch at first, another one below.

Comment: ok thanks mate it seems to have helped i'll try a further refactor it to increase effciency

Answer (score 1):

I really wish you'd post some sample data, rather not 45 fields wide and with 2502 chars in any of them. Post sample with 2 fields and reduce the width  to something reasonable, like 3:

```
$ cat file
A ""
A "123"
A "1234"
B ""
B "123"
B "1234"
```

Script:

```
$ awk '$1=="B" && $2~/^".{,3}"$/{print $0}' file
```

And its output (these should be your fail message but for demonstrational purposes):

```
B ""
B "123"
```

That would translate roughly to:

```
$ awk '$44=="B" && $45~/^".{,2500}"$/{print "45th field invalid-HEADER-FILE"}' file
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: look at op for sample

Comment: That's no sample input, that's a bunch of awk comparisons. Sample is a few records of a file a script can process. I can't feed that to my script. See my `cat file` for a sample of a sample.

Comment: @JamesBrown, right James sir, that is what I tried to mention and ask OP to provide full picture of question too.